# Atualizar linhas em arquivo ods usando python

Tags: python, arquivo

Estou a procura de uma forma de atualizar algumas linhas de um arquivo pre existente em formato ods usando a linguagem python.
Consegui criar um novo arquivo utilizando o bloco de código abaixo, mas a necessidade seria de atualizar um arquivo que ja existe.

```
import pyexcel_ods3 as pods

def lerPlanilha(planilha):
    data = pods.get_data(planilha)
    return data

parcela = lerPlanilha("PlanilhaBase.ods")

pods.save_data("saida.ods",parcela)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `get_data()` retorna uma instância de um `OrderedDict`, onde suas chaves representam a planilha e o valor de cada chave é uma *lista de listas*, representando a matriz de duas dimensões formada pelas células de cada planilha.

Por exemplo, assumindo que sua planilha de entrada seja algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código básico:

```
from pyexcel_ods3 import get_data
planilha = get_data("entrada.ods")
print(planilha)
```

Saída:

```
OrderedDict([('Sheet1', [['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], ['aeiou', 'kwy', 'blah']]), ('Sheet2', [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])])
```

A instância desse `OrderedDict` poderá ser manipulada/modificada a vontade e depois gravada novamente em arquivo, veja só:

```
from pyexcel_ods3 import get_data, save_data

# Carrega planilha
planilha = get_data("entrada.ods")

# Altera aleatoriamente o
# texto das celulas
planilha['Sheet1'][0][1] = 'bingo!'
planilha['Sheet1'][1][2] = 'kabum!'
planilha['Sheet1'][1][0] = 'shazam!'

# Multiplica por 2 todos os
# inteiros em todas a celulas
for linha in range(3):
    for coluna in range(4):
        n = planilha['Sheet2'][linha][coluna]
        planilha['Sheet2'][linha][coluna] = n * 2

# Grava planilha modificada
save_data("saida.ods", planilha)
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Lacobus, na madrugada anterioro eu havia conseguido resolver utilizando a biblioteca ezodf, pelo que pude percber o procedimento é semelhante ao que você indicou na resposta.